# Enumerate/Iterate over an array using Blocks and know when it is completed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, objective-c-blocks

I'd like to iterate through an array in Swift and I need to know when the last item has been reached. I am using *enumerateObjectsUsingBlock*. As there is no optional completion block (like in some of the CoreAnimation methods) I assume the **stop** parameter signals the end point – is this correct?

```
    itemsArray.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock {
        (object, index, stop) -> Void in
        self.displayedItems.addObject(object as SpecialItem)
        if stop == true {
           println("the end.")
        }
    }
```

*stop* seems to be of the type **UnsafeMutablePointer**. Therefore I cannot simply test it for being true/false or nil. How do I know when the enumeration is completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` executes *synchronously*. The enumeration is finished
when the method returns.

`stop` is a *reference* to a Boolean which can be set to `true` to stop further processing,
for example:

```
itemsArray.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock {
    (object, index, stop) -> Void in

    // process at most 5 elements:
    if index == 4 {
       stop.memory = true
    }
}
```

Testing `if stop == true` inside the block does not make sense.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. I thought blocks *always* work asynchronously … ups.

Comment: @BerndPlontsch: A block is more a less a piece of code (similar to a function, but with additional state like variable bindings). A block itself executes synchronously. It can be *used* for async methods like `dispatch_async()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Get the count prior to the block and then compare the index to the count to determine when you are at the last item.

If you just want to execute code after the enumeration is complete just put the code immediately following the block code. This block is not an asynchronous.

Note: Stop is a variable that can be set in the block to terminate enumeration early. See the documentation.